# Magento 2.2.8 - Possible Issues during upgrade?

Tags: magento2, magento2.2.8

Magento 2.2.8 was just released https://github.com/magento/magento2/releases/tag/2.2.8 . What are the issues that we might face during the upgrade ?

Comment: You can check it here - https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/329787/magento-2-show-whole-html-codephtml-file-code-into-pdf-file-and-download-with It is working properly.

Answer (score 0):

If you migrating from **2.2.x** version of Magento, I don't see there can be any major issues while upgrading.

Until and unless you Core files are modified you should go with an upgrade. **2.2.8** has covered many security and functional fixes which should be good for the website.

You can check in detail from [Release Note](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/release-notes/ReleaseNotes2.2.8CE.html)

If you are upgrading from **2.1.x or 2.0.x**, then there can be issues with upgrade considering there has been code level changes in Magento **2.2.x** from its predecessor.

Answer (score 0):

Upgrading from 2.2.7 > 2.2.8

If you have modules using bootstrap.php, you can have errors with Phar

The following was added to bootstrap.php in 2.2.8

```
`stream_wrapper_unregister('phar');`
```

Now I receive the error

```
[Exception] Warning: stream_wrapper_unregister(): Unable to unregister protocol phar:// in [DOCUMENT ROOT PATH]/html/app/bootstrap.php on line 11
```

At least that's what is happening to me on Nexcess servers, and I know Phar is enabled. I haven't been able to resolve or find a solution for this issue. The error doesn't show which module is causing the issue, but it seems to cause several issues for me.

1) The Authorize.net module now has the "Signature Key" field, but the "Merchant MD5" is still there, which I assume it shouldn't be and in var/log payments, I see the MD5 field is being populated. This causes a general failure on the site where the checkout fails on the frontend, has an error about the has being incorrect, but in the admin, the checkout shows as 'pending', but on Authorize.net, the transaction is approved and captured.

2) When editing a CMB block with a modal-pop-up, if WYSIWYG is enabled by default, or switched to, most of the js will be removed and the modal-pop-up will fail. A work around is to make sure to not enable WYSIWYG if editing a CMS block.

3) I'm sure it has something to do with #1, but if using CDN for pub/static/ and pub/media/ there's a very noticeable delay and images are the last thing that renders on the page. If not using CDN, there's still a lag, but it's much quicker. I'm using a saved .htaccess to allow the CDN, because the upgrade will overwrite the existing .htaccess

Nexcess has rather unique requirements for permissions, because it's a shared hosting environment, so the issue may be permissions causing the issues, but it has me stumped.